# Smoothness requirement for Stratonovich Integral

Tags: stochastic-analysis

Every place I've seen defines the Ito formula for the Stratonovich integral as $df(X_t) = f'(X_t) \circ dX_t$ for $f \in C^3(\mathbb{R})$ and $X_t$ brownian motion, while the Ito integral only requires $f \in C^2$. Why is this so? More explicitly, what is wrong with the following argument: Let $f \in C^2$ , $f \notin C^3$

$$f(X_t) \circ dX_t = f(X_t) dX_t + <df'(X_t),dX_t>$$

Thus, we'd like to say that $df'(X_t) = f''(X_t) dX_t + B.V.$ term. If we had this, then we'd recover the Ito formula.

$f \in C^2$ implies $f' \in C^1$. Choose a sequence $g_n \in C^\infty$ which converge to $f'$ in $C^1$-norm.

Then, by Ito's formula,

$$dg_n(X_t) = g'_n (X_t) dX_t + \frac{1}{2}g''_n (X_t) dt$$

Now, the left hand side converges to $df'(X_t)$ and the first term on the right converges to $f''(X_t)dX_t$. Thus, the final term must also converge to some process, which we shall $dL_t$.

Now, since $\frac{1}{2}g''_n (X_t) dt = \frac{1}{2} g''^{+}(X_t) - \frac{1}{2}g''^{-}(X_t)$ where the $+$ and $-$ denote the positive and negative parts respectively, then it's clear that each element in the sequence can be written as the difference of increasing functions. Since monotonicity is preserved under limits, then $dL_t$ must also be represented in that form, hence it is of (locally) bounded variation.

What did I do wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is indeed no need to assume $f \in C^3$; see e.g. René Schilling, Lothar Partzsch: *Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes*, Chapter 20 (2nd edition).

Comment: Chapter 20 of that book just looks like simulations and code. Am I missing something? I'm looking here: http://www.degruyter.com/view/supplement/9783110278989_Contents.pdf

Comment: That's the first edition, not the second edition.

Comment: I don't have Schillng-Partzsch near me, but the 2nd edition of Protter "Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations" also assumes only $C^2$ in a far more general case (see the discussion starting from p. 270).

Comment: I don't have either of those books, if you would like to type of the details and cite your reference, I would certainly reward you with the bounty.